# Synchronizing JTable and JTree

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way for a JTable and a JTree to share the same model, so that any change in that underlying model is reflected immediately in both components ?

Comment: Do you have a plan for mapping the row based order of table to the parent-child order of a tree?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there is a two part tutorial from Sun on creating tree tables, which is essentially a JTable with a JTree renderer in the first column.
tutorial links:
[part 1](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/)
[part 2](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable2/index.html)

EDIT:

On the topic of a TreeTable, (a Table component that maintains a tree in its first column, which allows for the hiding and displaying of rows based on the user's modifications of the Tree) I have found an implementation by NetBeans called `Outline`.  It is very easy to use.  A simple example took less than 30 minutes to mock up.  The code can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436281/help-making-a-jtree-with-a-jcheckbox/1436480#1436480).

Here is an image of the TreeTable:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/6643/picture1hz.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/6643/picture1hz.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a type `Obj` that can be represented both as a tree and a table, you can either create a `TableModel` and a `TreeModel` that observe changes to `Obj` and respond accordingly, you can make `Obj` implement both `TableModel` and `TreeModel` (although I don't like business objects implementing GUI objects), or you can create a class that implements both `TableModel` and `TreeModel` and knows when changes to `Obj` happen.

Answer (score 1):

Does this tutorial help:
http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces are different, but it should be totally doable to implement them using the same data structure below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want tree nodes containing the properties of each record and one table row per record, it shouldn't be too hard to create [adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for the TableModel and TreeModel interfaces based on a list of records.

Answer (score 0):

It's been stated, the best way is to create a datastructure(model) of some kind to represent your data, and then have the treemodel, and tablemodel look to the common datastructure to pull the data.  Doing this will allow both of them to share the same model, you will just need to fire the correct events when data changes so that both of them are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GlazedLists](http://www.publicobject.com/glazedlists/) -- there's an ability to use an EventList for both a JTable and a JTree. I'm not familiar with the JTree rendering, but the JTable part of GlazedLists is pretty solid.