# How to build a mix of JTree and JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to have a JTree which also displays some extra information right adjusted, just like there was an extra column, see picture below. Any hints for accomplishing something like this or similar are welcome!

[alt text http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/3671/exampleif.jpg](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/3671/exampleif.jpg)

Comment: There is such a common need for this component, I'm surprised the only decent result on Google is that ancient article. I'd have expected some library to have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some [articles at Sun about producing TreeTables in Java](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/).

I remember developing a TreeTable using the sample code as a great starting point, but these articles are 10 years old now so you may want to approach with a little caution.

If you'd like something newer there is the [NetBeans Outline Component](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component).

Comment: They definitely are pretty old by now. I started implementing such a thing a while ago, though development was done by another one later and I don't know in what shape the codebase is. If you're interested, you can download JAMES II at http://wwwmosi.informatik.uni-rostock.de/mosi/plonesoftwarecenter.2006-03-21.4262636143/pscproject.2006-03-21.6122697558/releases and take a look at the package `james.gui.utils.treetable`. The license should permit re-use outside that project.

Comment: I think I'll be able to put something together using this information, thanks.

Comment: +1 for the NetBeans Outline.  It is very simple to use.  See this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436281/help-making-a-jtree-with-a-jcheckbox/1436480#1436480

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this kind of thing by using and configuring the [JTreeTable from SwingX project](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingXTreeTable).

Comment: It's name is j_X_treetable and it comes without sorting: http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=484525&#484525 and without filtering: http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=234613