# How to get correct selection in a JTreeTable?

Tags: java, swing

I am working with a JTreeTable as described in an old article at: [Sun Developer Network](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/)

Here are the same files but slightly adjusted for java 6:
http://edtaylor80.angelfire.com

If you run this little example program you will find that selection works as expected to start with, entire rows are selected when you click a random cell. This behaviour is desired. However, as soon as a node is expanded the behaviour changes, now it is only possible to select a row by clicking at the actucal node (name). I still want to be able to select an entire row by clicking a random cell. How can I modify the source code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you click into the first column to open a node, there is no cell editor for the `JTable`.  Once you perform that operation, the table has an active cell editor, which is an instance of the `AbstractCellEditor` that comes as part of the `JTreeTable` example source.  In the implementation therein, you will find this:

```
public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) { return false; }
```

This gets called by the BasicTableUI when it determines whether to adjust selection or not.  As you can see, it will always return `false`.  This is why, once you open a node, you will see this odd selection behavior.

While on the topic of tree tables, I recommend that you check out NetBeans' `Outline`.  It is an easy to use implementation, much less convoluted than the JTreeTable example from Sun.  You can find links and a demo in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436281/help-making-a-jtree-with-a-jcheckbox/1436480#1436480).

Comment: That worked for me. And thanks for the point to the NetBeans Outline.

Comment: Thank you! I was reluctant to try the netbeans Outline at first, having a bad experience from JXTreeTable, with its crazy static invisible classes preventing you from changing the behavior of the component in a normal way, but the NetBeans thing seems great really! I have now added it to my Eclipse project!